# Asp.net Core Web API use Dapper to Execute Postgres function raise "Timeout during reading" and "Exception while reading from stream"

Tags: c#, postgresql, asp.net-core-webapi, dapper, azure-appservice

ASP.Net Core Web API use Dapper to execute Postgres function and get exception sometime
"Timeout during reading" and exception title is "Exception while reading from stream".

Web API deployed in Azure App service and Postgres is in Azure.

The Postgres connection string is given below.

```
Server=xyz.postgres.database.azure.com;Port=5432;Database=db1;Userid=user123;Password=pwd123;Timeout=120;Pooling=true;MinPoolSize=1;MaxPoolSize=30;Enlist=true;
```

Please give solution and reason for the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Although the information you supplied is lacking. If I had to guess, I would say you are encountering command timeout issues. The default command timeout is 30 seconds. I presume you are using NpgSql driver. [The documentation says that the default is 30 seconds](https://www.npgsql.org/doc/connection-string-parameters.html#timeouts-and-keepalive). Try to add the following to your connection string and see if the timeout still occurs.

```
Command Timeout=120;
```

This will set a timeout of 2 minutes

Comment: added "Command Timeout" property in the connection string but still getting the error.

Comment: Postgres log shows the following info.                                                                          2022-04-25 16:27:58 UTC-6266cc0d.a06e4-FATAL:  connection to client lost
2022-04-25 16:27:58 UTC-6266cc0e.a06e8-LOG:  connection received: host=xx.xxx.xx.xx port=xxx pid=xxxx
2022-04-25 16:27:58 UTC-6266cc0e.a06e8-LOG:  connection authorized: user=xxx=yyyyy SSL enabled (protocol=TLSv1.2, cipher=ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384, compression=off)
2022-04-25 16:28:39 UTC-6266cc0e.a06e8-LOG:  could not send data to client: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.

Comment: Can you report back of how long the query runs before timing out?

Comment: is there any way to check the how long query takes